# Can i use ipv6 without ipv4

Tags: webserver, ipv6, ipv4

I have dedicated server with ipv4 and ipv6.
I want to acess websites which has blocked my ip / subnet.
I was thinking is it possible that if i use ipv6 only and turn off ipv4 , then will i be able to visit the site , provided it didn't block ipv6.

Comment: In a word: "yes".

Comment: A VPN or proxy is much less effort and would work in more cases ...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time your ISP only gives you an IPv4 address. You can't simply say, I'll not use IPv4. So long story short: no you can't.

Internally you can use IPv6 only, but your ISP gives you an IPv4 address.

Keep in mind that the website you are visiting needs to support IPv6 too. If they don't, they can't block you, but you can't visit them either.

The other way around is true too. If they do use IPv6, they can block your IPv6 address just as easily too.

Comment: I think the idea is his network has been blacklisted (possibly for historical reasons), so it has been 'blocked' by the receiving end. He's not asking how he can 'block' it. He's asking if he can 'turn it off' (not literally) so IPv6 is preferred over IPv4. (In other words, I do not think your first two sentences are really relevant to the question - in this scenario, having an IPv4 address wouldn't matter if you're not using it for outgoing connections.)

Comment: @Bob my point is, if your ISP only gives you an IPv4 address and not an IPv6 address (still something that is very common) then you simply can't. But reading my answer back, I guess it was not that obvious. I'll edit.

Comment: "I have dedicated server with ipv4 and ipv6." => I suppose that isn't a problem for him. Assuming he's either connecting from that server, or tunneling through it. But the question is rather sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those websites and other resources run on servers that support do IPv6 - sure. However, IPv6 addresses are mostly unique (and if you have a few, they could block the whole range).

You would *also* tend to connect to IPv6 *then* try IPv4 in most dualstack implementations so "turning off ipv4" should be not needed.

Its worth figuring out why you're blocked before doing any of this as well.

Comment: I don't know about you, but on my ISP they do not provide an IPv6 address. I can't turn it off.

Comment: I did say dual stack, specifically - Mine *does* do native IPv6, but that's a rarity.